# Align multiple divs in one line and center text vertically and horizontally

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, centering, text-align

I want to align several `div`'s into **one line** and also `center` the content **vertically** and **horizontally**.

The text to align vertically could be a **single line**, or a **`<p>` paragraph**.

Comment: @wared : thankx for the share mate,really appreciate it but intentions are not bad from my side....in fact, i have seen lot of gold members posting similar way....watching those solution was a brain-child for this question to exist :)

Comment: I understand your idea, gold members' "self answered questions" are sometimes really helpful (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call), about quite hot topics, and also very well documented. Maybe your initiative will grow the same way :) Wish you luck :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To show n-number of `div`s in one line**, there are 3 approaches

- use `display:table;` 
   *This method is supported IE8 and above and comes in pretty handy if you have large amount of css and text and `div`s to align*
- use `float:left;`
  *All time favorite, the old school approach, this method is most recommended when old browser support has to be considered, requires `clear`ing of the float at the end*
- use `display:inline-block;`
  *never used this method personally float method was considered instead of using this by me*

**Base CSS**

```
/************Supported by IE8 and above *******************/
 div.table {
    width:100%;        /* important */
    display:table;
    text-align:center;
}
.table-cell {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
/************ Method 2 *******************/
 div.inline {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
div.inline-div {
    width:32%;
    display:inline-block;
}
/************ Method 3 *******************/
 .float-class {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
div.floatdiv {
    float:left;
    width:32%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.clearfloat {
    clear:both;
}
```

[**fiddle showing all three methods in 1 place**](http://jsfiddle.net/tBwL7/)

**To vertically center `one line` in a div**

again 3 approaches :
*keep in mind, solution has to be responive, so `margin-top:25% or 50%` is not gonna work*!!!

- `line-height`
  *this approach is usefull when the dimesnion of the parent div is known, then you can simply use the trick `line-height:equal to height of parent div`*
- `position`
  *idea is to make the `parent` positioned `relative` and the text span class an `absolute`, then center the `absolute` text using positioning like `top/bottom`*
- `display:table-cell`
  *highly recommended if IE7 and older support is not required, simply use `vertical-align:middle;`*

**Base css**

```
div.fixed-div-height {

    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
div.fixed-div-height span {
    line-height:200px; /* equal to height of the fixed div*/
}


div.unknown-div-height {
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    position: relative;
}
div.unknown-div-height > span.unknown-div-margin {
    display:inline-block;
    height:20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}


div.for-ie8-and-above{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
    height:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
div.for-ie8-and-above > div{
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle; /* key here */
}
```

[**fiddle showing all three methods**](http://jsfiddle.net/64nT6/)

**To center a paragraph vertically in center** 
*this is the tricky part*

Practically there is no possible way to `center` a `parapgraph` whose `height` and the `containers` `height` is unknown unless you gor for some hacks....one such hack has been quoted at the end of this answer from css tricks!!

Simplest, use :

```
div.table-cell {
    height:400px; /* can be anything, even in percentage*/
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;   /* key here */
}
```

[**fiddle showing remaining 2 possible cases**](http://jsfiddle.net/84PPD/1/)

Another solution posted here : 
**[How do I vertically center text with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-align-text-vertical-center-in-div-with-css)**

IE hack for `display:tables` :  [**CSS Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/)

Answer (score 1):

I aligned multiple divs within a table cell (td) by creating a container DIV, as follows:

```
<td>
    <div class="containingDIV"> // container DIV with CSS as below
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</td>
```

where css for containingDIV is:

```
.containingDIV {
    display: flex;
}
```