# How to align text without tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

How would you align text like this without tables?

http://jsfiddle.net/4xq55vg6/

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td>*</td>
   <td>Long Text</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>*</td>
  <td>Long Text</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Using CSS `text-align = value` ?

Comment: Err. Just `* Long Text`

Comment: or use `div`s and then align divs => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430203/align-multiple-divs-in-one-line-and-center-text-veticaly-and-horizontally

Comment: @NoobEditor using divs and aligning them is more difficult than text align

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I used a somewhat complex solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/4xq55vg6/10/

```
p
{
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    display: block;
}

p:before
{
    content: "*";
    margin-left: -1em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `display:inline-block` property

```
<div class="a">

    <p class="p1">*</p>
    <p  class="p2">kjwhkwgkufygajkfgxaskjfgkj hsgdfjkagsdkufygukasygfkjsghadfjkghfjkahgxf jasghdfkjaghxfkjkjasghfuhxg kjasdgh</p>
</div>
<div class="a">

    <p class="p1">*</p>
    <p  class="p2">kjwhkwgkufygajkfgxaskjfgkj hsgdfjkagsdkufygukasygfkjsghadfjkghfjkahgxf jasghdfkjaghxfkjkjasghfuhxg kjasdgh</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.p1{
    width:2%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.p2{
      width:80%;
    display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:top;
}
.a{
    width:600px;
}
```

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/cu2dpszf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with floating divs.

```
<div>
  <div class="leftDiv">*</div>
  <div class="rightDiv">Long Text</div>
  <div class="leftDiv">*</div>
  <div class="rightDiv">Long Text</div>
</div>
```

and then float them next to each other in the CSS

```
.leftDiv
{
    clear:both;
    width:5%;
    float:left;
}
.rightDiv
{
    width:95%;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6kwbm0b/

Comment: The 5% does not cause the same appearance as the original. And the text will flow into the asterix when you make the screen pretty narrow.

Comment: The 5% was more for example, would probably be better as 1em with hindsight, although this would cause the right div to flow under as the screen size diminishes.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this

```
td{
text-align:center;
}
```

you can use right center left justify values for text-align

Answer (score -1):

Like this:

```
<div style="width:100%;text-align:center">Hello</div>
```

Of course you shouldn't use inline-styles. Better:

```
<div class="aClass">Hello</div>


.aClass{text-align:center;width:100%;}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin-left: 0;
      padding-left: 1em;
      text-indent: -1em;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>* This is a ... ng it?</li>
  <li>* And here is an ... way of doing it?</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4xq55vg6/5/

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the fiddle you can keep those lines in `<p>` tag and in CSS add a `content: "*"` before

HTML

```
<p>This is a long text... </p>
<p>And here is another text....</p>
```

CSS

```
p:before { content: "*"}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anpsmn/4xq55vg6/2/)

Comment: Nice and simple but the wrapped text will remain under the asterisk and will not stay in it's own 'cell'

Comment: Aah, then you will have to have a new element for * and have it floated like in  other answers